# assertion error while using opencv's background subtractor

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 via python3.
Unfortunately my code has unexpectedly become unusable by this assertion error:

```
cv2.error: /home/user/Downloads/opencv/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:4774:
error: (-215) clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS in function map
```

This follows some library updates that I have been installing, including NVidia stuff.
This exception seems to originate from the C++ code. The last python function that is called before the exception is: `bgSubtractor.apply(roi)`.

Any idea on how to interpret this assertion error? A bug in OpenCV or is there a more simple explanation?

Comment: The `clEnqueueReadBuffer`may fail because you are out of memory. Are you working with large images or do you have very little GPU VRAM (Intel Integrated GPU with very little VRAM configured)?

Comment: grain of salt: my intel hd400 igpu shares only 1.5 GB region of RAM

Comment: I am using an ASUS DirectCU II with 3GB, so it's likely that the problem is not lack of ram, also because this problem emerged after software changes (many libraries, Ubuntu and nvidia module updated), while the hardware staid the same. Moreover, the task in question is just background subtraction of HD images, so there should be plenty of memory for that.